# XSLT error when trying to match an element that is following sibling of another element

Tags: xslt, xpath

I'm having difficulty matching an element that is a following sibling of another element.

```
<w:p>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:color w:val="002D56"/>
            <w:sz w:val="44"/>
            <w:szCs w:val="44"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>I want to match this...</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
         <w:rPr>
             <w:rFonts w:cstheme="minorHAnsi"/>
             <w:sz w:val="28"/>
             <w:szCs w:val="28"/>
         </w:rPr>
         <w:t>...but I don't want to match this.</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

With

```
<xsl:template match="w:rPr[w:sz[@w:val='44']]"> ...
```

I'm finding the preceding sibling (the first w:rPr element in the sample above), but if I try

```
<xsl:template match="w:rPr[w:sz[@w:val='44']]/following-sibling::w:t"> ...
```

I get an error that the pattern failed to compile (`XSLTParseError: xsltCompilePattern : failed to compile`).

I'm assuming the problem is with my XPath, but I can't figure out what. Suggestions?

Comment: Your two xpaths seem to be fine. Can you post the full error ? And did you define namespace `w`?

Comment: XSLT pattern syntax is a subset of XPath expression syntax. You can't use the following-sibling axis (except within a predicate, where full XPath is allowed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reversing your logic, and match the `w:t` whose preceding sibling is the `w:rPr` matching your conditions

```
<xsl:template match="w:t[preceding-sibling::w:rPr[w:sz/@w:val='44']]">
```

Note, you could also try this, but this would match `w:t` that were either following or preceding siblings

```
<xsl:template match="w:r[w:rPr/w:sz/@w:val='44']/w:t">
```

Answer (score 2):

There's another approach which I've sometimes used here, which is to define global variables that contain all the nodes of a particular kind, and then use these global variables in patterns. For example:

```
<xsl:variable name="wonderElements"
         select="//w:rPr[w:sz[@w:val='44']]/following-sibling::w:t"/>
```

XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:template match="*[. intersect $wonderElements]"/>
```

XSLT 3.0:

```
<xsl:template match="$wonderElements"/>
```

Officially XSLT 1.0 doesn't allow global variables in match patterns, though I believe some processors lift this restriction.